# What is the best way to save and restore the controlling commands

Tags: android

I'm new in android and I have an android app which controls a robot wirelessly.
Can anyone please offer an advice to me  about the best way to save and restore the controlling commands for example should I use external file or android's register ...

Comment: What do you mean by controlling commands? Are they some constant values you send to the robot?

Comment: I mean the movement commands like (left, right, forward..) and the period of time it took to each command.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the number of commands. If it is a large number, you can use [`SQLite` Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db), if there are only a few, you can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Both options are embedded and integrated in the Android environment.

Answer (score 1):

First, you gotta check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) post to understand the options of storing data in Android. Then you can decide what option to use. Hope this helps.